# How to iterate over property to get count or length having same value using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, loops

I have the following object, Please let me know how to iterate over this object to get the `count/length` of the `property(category)` value to know how many times it is repeated.

like:

```
FIRST is repeated one-time(i.e count or length: 1)
    SECOND is repeated three times(i.e count or length: 3)
    THIRD is repeated three times(i.e count or length: 3)
    FOURTH is repeated one-time (i.e count or length: 1)
```

var categorycount =

```
    [{"name":"ABC","vals":[{"description":"first description","category":"FIRST"},
    {"description":"second description","category":"SECOND"},
    {"description":"third description","category":"SECOND"},
    {"description":"fourth description","category":"SECOND"},
    {"description":"fifth description","category":"THIRD"},
    {"description":"sixth description","category":"THIRD"}, 
    {"description":"eighth description","category":"THIRD"},
    {"description":"ninth description","category":"FOURTH"},

    ]}];
    var obj = JSON.stringify(categorycount[0].vals);
    console.log(obj);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mavdhana/8kbgt1cr/5/).

Comment: Did you try using array's reduce method for the same?

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi, thank you for your response, i tried with array.reduce() or forEach(), but I am not getting my output like above.

Comment: Are you need only count it? Any mutation?

Comment: @DimaVak, yes, i need count of iterated property having same value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using a [reducer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function?

```js
var categorycount = [
  {
    name: 'ABC',
    vals: [
      { description: 'first description', category: 'FIRST' },
      { description: 'second description', category: 'SECOND' },
      { description: 'third description', category: 'SECOND' },
      { description: 'fourth description', category: 'SECOND' },
      { description: 'fifth description', category: 'THIRD' },
      { description: 'sixth description', category: 'THIRD' },
      { description: 'eighth description', category: 'THIRD' },
      { description: 'ninth description', category: 'FOURTH' },
    ],
  },
]

const res = categorycount[0].vals.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur.category] = acc[cur.category] ? acc[cur.category] + 1 : 1
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(res)
```

Comment: yes. it is fine well. Thank you for your help :-)

Answer (score 1):

@Dhana, I wrote this using forEach loop

```
const result={};

categorycount[0].vals.forEach(ob => {

    if(result[ob.category]){
    result[ob.category]=result[ob.category]+1;
  } else {
    result[ob.category]=1;
  }
})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: yes, it is fine with forEach(). Thank you for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know or it a good way, but it works.

```js
var categorycount = 

[{"name":"ABC","vals":[{"description":"first description","category":"FIRST"},
{"description":"second description","category":"SECOND"},
{"description":"third description","category":"SECOND"},
{"description":"fourth description","category":"SECOND"},
{"description":"fifth description","category":"THIRD"},
{"description":"sixth description","category":"THIRD"}, 
{"description":"eighth description","category":"THIRD"},
{"description":"ninth description","category":"FOURTH"},
]}];
var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(categorycount[0].vals))

console.log('FIRST: ' + obj.filter(z => z.category == "FIRST").length)
console.log('SECOND: ' + obj.filter(z => z.category == "SECOND").length)
console.log('THIRD: ' + obj.filter(z => z.category == "THIRD").length)
console.log('FOURTH: ' + obj.filter(z => z.category == "FOURTH").length)
```

Comment: yes. it is fine. Thank you for your help :-)